# Linking Outlook.com mail account and Mac Mail via Active Sync

Tags: mail.app, email, exchange-activesync

I've setup a new outlook.com account and I'm trying to add it to Mac Mail. In the past when I've had Gmail account they've allowed me to use IMAP, but with Outlook.com you don't have that option - only POP3 or Active Sync. I don't want to use POP3 as it doesn't sync the back to the server, so I want to use Active Sync, which works in a similar way to IMAP in terms of syncing everything.

How can I add an Active Sync account to Mac Mail? I've had a look around but could find any info on it, any ideas?

Comment: You could try to configure it as a "Microsoft Exchange" account (directly in Mail.app or in Mountain Lion via System prefs -> Mail, Contacts & Calendar). I've once heard, that Microsoft doesn't support the Exchange sync on Desktop operating systems, but I don't know if this is actually true. You could simply try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook.com now supports IMAP and can be configured to work in Mac Mail. Take a look at the following [Microsoft Community answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-email/how-to-set-up-mac-mail-to-sync-your-outlookcom/afdfe981-20c7-4d4a-b6b1-9329b27f018a?tm=1379009343708).

> 1. Open Mac Mail.
> 2. From the File menu, choose Add Account…
> 3. Input your account information.
> 4. Choose Account Type: IMAP.
> 5. Input the following as the Incoming Mail Server: `imap-mail.outlook.com`.
> 6. Choose to Use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for incoming mail security.
> 7. Input the following as the Outgoing Mail Server: `smtp-mail.outlook.com`.
> 8. Choose to Use Authentication.
> 9. Choose to Use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for outgoing mail security.

Comment: Thanks very much - that makes the whole thing MUCH simpler

Comment: @sam you should probably give Paul the correct answer now that the situation has changed with IMAP support.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook.com supports [POP3 or Exchange ActiveSync](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app). Mac Mail only supports Exchange proper, not Exchange ActiveSync.

The only third-party client I found to support Exchange ActiveSync is [Mbox Mail](http://fluentfactory.com/mboxmail-for-mac/), but judging from their website, it has not been updated in quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

Summarized IMAP connection info (above does not contain ports to be used):

---

**Incoming (IMAP) Server**

- Server address: imap-mail.outlook.com
- Port: 993
- Encrypted Connection:
  SSL

**Outgoing (SMTP) Server**

- Server address: smtp-mail.outlook.com
- Port: 25 (or 587 if 25 is blocked)
- Authentication: Yes
- Encrypted Connection: TLS

**User name**: Your email address

**Password**: Your password

---

I have used these settings and it works quite well so far.

Cheers!

EDIT: be sure to change your archive and sent email folders in the Mac app as they tend to create new ones!

Answer (score 0):

i did youse these imap server adresses, but the main Inboxfolder doesn't get synced.
The other folders are synced but have to be added manuel.
Thats same in Apple Mail and Outlook 2011 for mac.

Mbox Mail doesn't work at all
Do you have any idea

Thanks a lot

Comment: This might need some editing to help explain what you are saying. Since the asker already has indicated the problem is solved, perhaps you might edit the accepted answer if you can't edit this into shape.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TouchDown](http://nitrodesk.com). It works on my Mac perfectly.

Comment: Touchdown has some bugs in forward the mails with deleting the content which do not want to forward to the recipient. Even we remove the content and forward the mails to any others, entire mail is sent to the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (I presume), it works if you configure your Outlook.com mail address as Exchange Connection under "Internet-accounts" in Settings.app

Best Regards